# Coding ISO Week of Year - Week 53 Problems

Tags: algorithm, time, iso, iso8601, week-number

I'm trying to code a function to find the ISO week of the year. I found the [ISO Week Wiki Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Algorithms) about it that included this Algorithm:

```
woy = (10 + doy − dow) div 7
```

It works for the most part, but I'm having two issues and not sure how to fix it.

Issue 1) Week 53's that really should be Week 1. (I.e. 20191230 to 20191231) Which come out as Week 53, but should be Week 1.

Issue 2) Week 53's of Leap Years. (I.e. 20210101 to 20210103) Which are coming out as Week 0, but should be Week 53.

Is there a clean way to alter/add to that formula to account for those above problems?

Comment: What are the available inputs you have? Only day-of-year and day-of-week? Or do you have logic to add one or more days to date? Or otherwise, what is your programming environment, and what is the input (Date object? A serial number? Separate values for date parts, ...)? The simplicity of a formula depends on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cited Wikipedia article does include instructions for these boundary cases:

> - If the week number thus obtained equals 0, it means that the given date belongs to the preceding (week-based) year.
> - If a week number of 53 is obtained, one must check that the date is not actually in week 1 of the following year.
>
> [image]

The downside here is that you still need a function `weeks`. If you don't have that easily available, then here is another approach:

1. Move the given date to match the Thursday in the *same* week. So for a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, you would go backwards, and for the other days (except Thursday) you would move forwards in time. Obviously the output for that Thursday should be same, since we stay in the same week.
2. Apply the formula for *that* date. Obviously `dow` will always be 4 now (Thursday), so the formula simplifies to `(6 + doy) div 7`

Let's use this method on the examples you have given:

- 30 December 2019 is a Monday, so we move forward to Thursday 2 January 2020. For that date, `doy` is 2, and the formula `(6 + doy) div 7` gives 1 as result.
- 1 January 2021 is a Friday, so we move backward to Thursday 31 December 2020. For that date, `doy` is 366, and the formula `(6 + doy) div 7` gives 53 as result.

Comment: Thanks for the help/insight! - I'll work to implement the second option you pointed out. -  I am intrigued by the first option, but not sure what the "weeks" function would be? I can program this myself if I know what it does? Is it as simple as number of days in a year / 7, or something more complicated?

Comment: "What is the weeks() function" is the question! It is the number of ISO weeks in the given year. I created a function based upon this sentence: "... if a Gregorian year contains 52 Thursdays then the corresponding ISO calendar year has 52 weeks and if the Gregorian year contains 53 Thursdays then the corresponding ISO calendar year has 53 weeks." from https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/calendar/isocalendar_text_2.htm.